# Unable to delete set of video files using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have written a shell script to delete a set of video files (.0 format) which are 81 or more days older in putty using the following:

```
find /data/local_0/ -type f  -name "*.0" -mtime +80 -exec rm {}\;
```

When I execute this command, I'm getting the following exception.

```
[root@server /]# find /data/local_0/ -type f  -name "*.0" -mtime +50
find: /data/local_0/: Value too large for defined data type
```

I also tried to delete forcefully but same exception popped up. How to resolve  this exception?
i have added [a screen shot as evidence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEOFO.png), too.

Comment: what is the output of `find /path / -type f  -name ".0" -mtime +80` is it giving you files you want to be deleted?

Comment: and is there a space in `/path /` ? it will result in searching through entire root directory

Comment: @sp asic, no its not giving files that i want to delete. i'm getting same exception for this command also.

Comment: and there is no space in path, the path i specified is /data/local_0

Comment: can you give example of files you want to match.. `".0"` will match exactly a file named `.0` have a look at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob on how to use globbing pattern

Comment: also see: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/faq/coreutils-faq.html#Value-too-large-for-defined-data-type for 'Value too large for defined data type' message

Comment: This is an example of sample video file (.0): "0a1c6fc4-1dd2-11b2-8529-bc990bb718a8.0" ,i missed the * infront of .0 while typing, i edited the question please have a look.

Comment: have you checked this faq https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/faq/coreutils-faq.html#Value-too-large-for-defined-data-type?

Comment: It seems impossible that `find` or `rm` could produce this error message. Voting to close as unreproducible.

Comment: @tripleee  - i have provided screen shot of error please take a look. same thing is popping up with remove command

Comment: Ack - removed downvote and retrac ed cose vote; sorry about that. Is `/data/local_0/` a separate partition? Does it contain some realny large files, or a really big file system? I think @spasic basically aready told us what's wrong.

Comment: @sp asic - the link  was useful . thanks

Comment: @MS.Rajesh glad to know, please post an answer if you were able to resolve